# Unable to uninstall applications via Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: software-center, uninstall

I am running Ubuntu 10.04

Recently I tried to uninstall apps from Ubuntu Software centre, but it shows the app is uninstalled, but with some error. When I check the application from App Menu, It shows the icon, but upon clicking it shows error. I want to get rid of this. Please help me fix the problem.

```
  installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 309049 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing prism-google-talk ...
Removing prism ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_IN.ISO8859-1.cache...
WARNING: System locale is invalid
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Unknown media type in type 'interface/x-winamp-skin'
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Setting up bandwidthd (2.0.1) ...
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/bandwidthd missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
/etc/init.d/bandwidthd: 19: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
invoke-rc.d: initscript bandwidthd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bandwidthd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bandwidthd
Setting up bandwidthd (2.0.1) ...
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/bandwidthd missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
/etc/init.d/bandwidthd: 19: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
invoke-rc.d: initscript bandwidthd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bandwidthd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your locale, i.e. your language, time and date format. I don't remember exactly what it looks like in 10.04, but you should be able to find it in the System menu. In 12.04, it's called "Language Support".

Make sure your language settings are correct and that you have installed the languages you're using. You should also apply your changes to the entire system. In 12.04 this is called "Apply System-Wide".

Comment: I have done this. But still facing the same problem..